# could not execute query; SQL nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a native  SQL query like this, But when I run my program and I got an Error message like my topic. But In normal SQL (without Hibernate) My query works fine..I am a new student for spring and hibernate. I really need your help.

```
   @Query(value = "select b.bookingID,b.rentDate,b.returnDate,b.custNICNumber,b.bookingStatus,rd.lossDamage,rd.driverNICNumber,rd.vehicleRegID " +
            "from booking b,bookingdetails rd where (b.bookingID=rd.bookingID) and b.bookingStatus='Rejected' && rd.vehicleRegID=?", nativeQuery = true)
    Booking getReturn(String vehicleRegID);
```

My Booking Entity  -

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Booking {
    @Id
    private String bookingID;
    private Date rentDate;
    private Date returnDate;
    private String bookingStatus; //For Admin Approvel
    private String rentStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "custNICNumber", referencedColumnName = "custNICNumber")
    private Customer custNICNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookingID")
    private List<BookingDetails> bookingDetails = new ArrayList<>();
```

My BookignDetails Entity -

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class BookingDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int bookingDetailsID;
    private double lossDamage;
    private String lossDamageImage;


    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookingID", referencedColumnName = "bookingID")
    private Booking bookingID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleRegID", referencedColumnName = "vehicleRegID")
    private Vehicle vehicleRegID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driverNICNumber", referencedColumnName = "driverNICNumber",nullable = true)
    private Drivers driverNICNumber;
```

Thank You Very Much..!

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses the '&&' operator, it should be AND

```
b.bookingStatus='Rejected' && rd.vehicleRegID=?
```